# Unobtrusive Validation doesn't work when inputs have HTML 5 attributes such as type='tel'

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I have the MVC 4 unobtrusive validation and it works well when the input types are "text" as soon as I change to html 5 types i.e type="tel", Client-side validation no longer works.

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact person's business phone number is required.")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{0,15}$", ErrorMessage = "PhoneNumber should contain only numbers")]
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
public string contactBusinessPhone { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group float-label-control">
    <label for="">
        Business Phone</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-1x"></i></span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.businessInfo.contactBuisnessPhone, new { type = "tel", @class = "form-control requiredField", placeholder = "Business Phone", data_mask = "000-000-0000" })
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.businessInfo.contactBusinessPhone, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. I assume `data_mask` is associated with some jquery plugin so its likely that is causing the problem

Comment: I removed the masking jquery, and still i cannot get the client-side validation when the type of the input is other than text. On Firebug, if i change the type then the validation works.

Comment: WOw....Found the issue...I was working on a form wizard so the validation was customized to do on clicking next, i did not include the html5 attributes. IT is all working.

Answer (score 0):

WOw....Found the issue...I was working on a form wizard so the validation was customized to do on clicking next, i did not include the html5 attributes. IT is all working.